# What's the purpose of passing in global variables into a self-invoking function when it has access to global variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What's the purpose of passing in global variables into a self-invoking function when it has access to global variables in javascript?

For example,

```
(function(window, undefined){
    console.log('Hello World!'); 
})(window, undefined);
```

What's the purpose of referencing the window as an argument to this self-invoking function when it has access to the global window object without passing it in?

Comment: My guess is to reduce or prevent closures by not accessing variables outside of its own scope.  Although, if you don't actually use the variable passed in, there seems little point either way.

Comment: Usually `undefined` is not passed, only "received", hence it is really `undefined` within the function. This is a trick from the days, when you could override the `undefined` with an arbitrary value.

Comment: @Teemu—those days are still with us. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example provided:

```
(function(window, undefined){
    console.log('Hello World!'); 
})(window, undefined);
```

the intention is to ensure that *window* within the IIFE references the global (window) object, and that the identifier *undefined* has the [*undefined* value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.9).

However, both those identifiers may have already been assigned some other value before this code runs, so it misses the point. To achieve the intended outcome with certainty, *this* can be used to unequivocally reference the global object (i.e. *window* in a browser) and the *undefined value* doesn't need to be passed in at all (assuming that this is global code).

Consider:

```
(function (window, undefined) {
    console.log('Hello World!'); 
})(this);
```

or if you're really paranoid:

```
(function (window) {
    var undefined = void 0;
    console.log('Hello World!'); 
})(this);
```

That code can be placed anywhere in the global context and guarantee that within the IIFE, the identifier *window* references the global object and *undefined* has the *undefined value*.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the this object as the true argument for the window object

Answer (score 0):

There would be no point at all in the example you show. But it does create scope within the self-executing function, for variables that are not global.

Comment: I see your point, if the self-invoking function was in a different scope other than global scope...